# nameservice1 error when loading data in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am trying to load a flat file in a table in hive and get below error.
FAILED: IllegalArgumentException java.net.UnknownHostException: nameservice1

Not sure what is required to do here.

The table is created as 
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS poc_yi2 ( IndexValid_fg STRING ) ROW FORMAT delimited fields terminated by ',' STORED AS TEXTFILE

The data file contains one line which is
Yes,

The command to load the data is:
load data local inpath '/home/user1/testx/1' overwrite into table poc_yi2;

Is this a configuration param? I am relatively new to Hive. Can someone please assist

Comment: Your problem looks identical to this https://groups.google.com/a/cloudera.org/forum/#!msg/cdh-user/cax7rH3cYms/Ef2OTN1QkYAJ

Answer (score 1):

Looks like some problem with your cluster configuration. Please make sure you have properly set the properties like :

```
dfs.nameservices=nameservice1

dfs.ha.namenodes.nameservice1=namenode1,namenode2
```

Stop the daemons, make all the necessary modifications and restart your cluster. If the problem still persists, please show me your log files along with the config files.